# Convert a 2D list of numbers to a ImageCollection with constant values in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, array

I have climate indices values as lists and I tried to make the lists into an imageCollection.
However, when I tried to use map function,

```
var climate_indices =  ee.ImageCollection.fromImages(
  years.map(function (y) {
    return months.map(function(m) {
      var monthID = m;
      var yearID = y;

      var dmiImage = ee.Image(dmi.get([yearID-2000,monthID-1])).rename('dmi').float();
      var meiImage = ee.Image(mei.get([yearID-2000,monthID-1])).rename('mei').float();
      var pdoImage = ee.Image(pdo.get([yearID-2000,monthID-1])).rename('pdo').float();

      var w = dmiImage.addBands(meiImage).addBands(pdoImage); 
      return w.set('year', y)
              .set('month', m)
              .set('system:time_start', ee.Date.fromYMD(y, m, 1));
                        
    });
  }).flatten()
);
print(climate_indices)
```

The system report:

> "Array.get: Element 0 of list 'position' must not be null."

It seems that the m or y here is seen as Null.
Anyone could help with that?

https://code.earthengine.google.com/41c17638e32ab0d2c922f46ffb215ef6

Answer (score 0):

`yearID` and and `monthID` are server-side objects, which can't do math with client-side objects. As an example of this,

```
print(ee.Number(5) - 5) // NaN
```

So in your script, you end up indexing into your arrays (e.g. `dmi`) with a `NaN`.

A solution would be to cast your indexing variables to a client-side object before indexing into your arrays. Example:

```
var row = ee.Number(y).subtract(2000)
var col = ee.Number(m).subtract(1)

var dmiImage = ee.Image(dmi.get([row,col])).rename('dmi').float();
```